# Getting specific row count in json using c#

Tags: c#, json, rest

```
{
    "rowcount":"1",
    "projectAgeGroupCollection":
    [
      {"projectKey":"EI452","lowAge":"0","highAge":"0","schoolMonths":"January,February,March,April,July,August,September,October,November","schoolDays":"Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday","schoolHours":"4"}
    ]
}
```

I want to retreive only the index part of json string..i.e `[key:value]`

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: yes,using JObject class i tried..but still getting exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

I assume you have json in string "response"

```
dynamic deserializedToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
accessToken = deserializedToken.access_token;
```

note that acess_token is name of property in json. 
jsonconvert is in newtonsoft.json (nuget package - find in package manager in Visual Studio)

Comment: Well,i am getting proper response till this line
RestResponse restresponse = (RestResponse)restclient.Execute(req);                            
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(restresponse.Content);
Can you suggest futher step,i tried to use foreach as well.

Comment: I think in this case will not be bossible foreach scenario because you have array of objects. to get property name "lowAge" you schould try this : `json.projectAgeGroupCollection[0].lowAge` or you can go foreach `foreach (var obj in json.projectAgeGroupCollection) { string lowAge = obj.lowAge` please be aware of case sensitivity, this code will compile but in case of some error it will be seen only in runtime. also try to put breakpoint and go with mouse over variable you schould see properties